# AngularJS: templateUrl from a different domain is blocked

Tags: angularjs

I'm writing an app that will be embedded in other sites. the javascript resources will be hosted on my server and people can embed it to their site. the problem is i have a directive with a templateUrl, and the template html file is also on my server. when i run the app from the client server the script is blocked due to cross site limitation caused by the template file. if I use a template string instead of templateUrl it works smoothly, but I would like to avoid it because it's a very long template. Any thoughts how to accomplish this?

Comment: could you give us some code to work with please, this all sounds conceptual right now, is this all entirely in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely not to be an issue with templates in particular but any cross origin requests within your app.

To enable CORS on your server you want to return the header like `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`. Note that this allows requests from any client, you can limit by changing `*` to your client domain.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue some time back.
You need to your server to be CORS compatible.
You need your server to return the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`